# Mechanism of destroying an object by CLR in c#.net

Tags: c#, memory-management, resources, clr, using-statement

We can declare a destructor but we do not know when it run, Since it is decided by CLR when to destroy an object that is no longer referenced by any type variable. CLR decides it by using garbage collector which build map for all reachable objects and deallocate unreachable objects (objects that has no reference).

Here it is clear that we can never destroy an object by our own code in c#.

Now

When we use using statement (not using directive) as shown below

```
using(ManageMe manage = new ManageMe())
        {
            manage.Add(4,8);
            Console.WriteLine("using statement executed");
        }
```

> Q1: What happens to the object that is reference by manage (type variable) after end of using statement? Means is it destroyed or CLR decide to destroy when it needs?
>
> Q2: How we can check that whether an object that is not reference by any type variable is destroyed or not during execution of my programme?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Q1: What happens to the object that is reference by manage (type
>   variable) after end of using statement? Means is it destroyed or CLR
>   decide to destroy when it needs?

It happens whatever happens to a local method reference.

> Q2: How we can check that whether an object that is not reference by
>   any type variable is destroyed or not during execution of my
>   programme?

I'll answer this *question* with a new question: **how can you check a reference against any condition if you don't own the whole reference?** An object lives in memory unless there's no reference pointing to that given object. Otherwise, the *garbage collector* will collect it as soon as it's fired automatically by the *CLR*. In other words: **if your program has no reference to an object, you can be sure that object will be garbage-collected**.

That is, the *garbage-collector* may collect the object implementing `IDisposable`  and it'll be able to reclaim its memory **but the underlying resources required and used by the whole object will be still alive because the garbage collector won't call `IDisposable.Dispose` for you**.

### The problem with your question: IDisposable pattern has nothing to do with garbage collection

`IDisposable` interface has nothing to do with garbage collection. It's just an interface to define objects capable of releasing resources. These *resources* can be whatever:

- A file system lock.
- A TCP port.
- A database connection.
- ...

Usually, `IDisposable` is implemented by classes handling unmanaged resources and, since they're *unmanaged*, you need to manually *dispose* them. Otherwise, they would be released by *garbage collector* (which handles managed resources, of course...).

In the other hand, `using` statement is just a `try-finally` simplification:

```
using(ManageMe manage = new ManageMe())
{
     manage.Add(4,8);
     Console.WriteLine("using statement executed");
}
```

...is:

```
ManageMe manage = new ManageMe();
try 
{
     manage.Add(4,8);
     Console.WriteLine("using statement executed");
}
finally 
{
    manage.Dispose();
}
```

Thus, as I said in my answer to your **Q1**, an `using` block is just syntactic sugar to be sure that `IDisposable.Dispose` method will be called once the block ends. The `using` block expects an `IDisposable` which can be either a variable declaration of the `IDisposable` itself:

```
ManageMe me = new ManageMe();
using(me) 
{

}
```